# How to add an "all" group in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe that i want to analyze by groups. I can do that easily by the following. But  I also want to add an "all" group without having to make extra copies of the data. So instead of 2 separate disjoint groups, i want to add another group that includes everything. The use case is that i want to iterate over each group and an all group as to keep everything readable.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ['good', 'good', 'bad'], 'B' :[4,2,1], 'C':[10,10,10]})
df_groups=df.groupby('A')
for group, df in df_groups:
    print group
    //do group level computation
```

for example I want to do the iteration by something like

```
for group, df in zip(df_groups.groups.keys() + ['all'], df_groups.groups.values() + df_groups.groups.values()):
    print group
    //do group level computation. This time on each group, and also an all group.
```

Comment: I don't understand your issue, if you process each group + all data, then you'll process your data twice?

Comment: Yes i need to process the data differently. Let's say i  need to calculate standard deviation (np.std), on each group and also on all.

Comment: Why don't you just do that without using groupby?

Comment: I suppose I could do it without groupby, by getting the unique names of the group that i want to group by. However, this seems like this would be much slower.

Comment: That's not what I meant. If you have, say 3 groups, and you want to calculate the std for each group and the total std (which you refer as 'all'), you can use `df.groupby('A').std()` for the groups and `df.std()` for the total std.

Comment: Ah OK. So I don't want to do that because I want to iterate (i have many operations that i want to be doing over the groups, i.e. .std() .sum() and many more for example). Your way I'd have to be naming all the groups one by one or  it will still be two parts 1) iteration over all groups and then 2) over the entire group.  I'd rather just somehow add  a group called "all" to the iteration process.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `margin` parameter of the `pivot_table` function to `True` to obtain a total ('All').

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['good', 'good', 'bad'], 'B' :[4,2,1], 'C':[10,10,10]})

pd.pivot_table(df, index=['A'], aggfunc=np.sum, margins=True)

      B   C
A          
bad   1  10
good  6  20
All   7  30
```